# Word 2016 Converting single column table to comma-delimited

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016

I'm constantly having to replace `^p` with `,` in Word 2016 because I can't get it to convert to comma separated values.  I think it's a bug; I don't think I'm doing something wrong with converting table to text, but I'm checking here before whispering in the wind on https://word.uservoice.com/

Steps to reproduce:

1. Copy ***single column*** of values from Excel
2. Paste into Word 2016 (match destination formatting)
3. Select Table
4. Go to Table Tools > Layout (y'know, because MS thought having two Layout tabs was a great design choice; it's been eight years and I still feel strangled by The Ribbon)
5. Click Convert to Text
6. Choose either Commas, or Other (with a Comma or Comma+Space)

Result:

- Paragraph delimited list

Expected Result:

- Comma delimited list

Comment: This is the way it's supposed to work, no bug.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc I guess I just needed someone to tell me I was wrong, and suddenly my mistake jumped out at me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see my issue: when converting a table to text, columns get specified delimiters, rows get paragraph marks.

So, to do what I was expecting, I first have to transpose (easy enough in Excel as one of the paste types).